# Connes's unpublished manuscript on correspondences, anyone?

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras, reference-request

There exist unpublished notes on correspondences of von Neumann algebras due to Connes. This is often cited, but I've never seen a copy. It would be nice to have this, say, to maybe look further into the point of view discussed in his book *Noncommutative geometry*. Particularly, the stuff involving half-densities.

Does anyone have a scanned copy of this they wouldn't mind sending/posting a link to?

Thanks, in advance!

Answer (score 7):

Aren't you thinking of Popa's unpublished manuscript on Correspondences, available on his website:
http://www.math.ucla.edu/~popa/popa-correspondences.pdf

Comment: Thanks, Alain! I do, in fact, mean unpublished notes of Connes, though. I wonder if Sorin Popa would have a copy of these?

Comment: I see. These might be handwritten notes by Connes, dated 1980, right? I don't have them. Most probably Sorin has a copy, or Dima, or Claire Anantharaman-Delaroche...

Comment: Yes, these are the notes I'm referring to.

Comment: I wonder if these notes more or less are contained in Connes's book? I have never seen the notes, so I don't know.

Comment: Hi @JonBannon :) Looking in the draft book of CAD & Popa, they say at one point: "the notion of bimodule was introduced by Connes in the beginning of the eighties...The content of his unpublished manuscript notes that were circulated at that time may be found in his book [Con94, V. Appendix B] where bimodules are called correspondences." Perhaps you already saw the stuff in his book?

Comment: Interesting! I guess this answers the question, right?